# Linq ToList does nothing

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have `Option Strict` and `Option Infer` both set "On".

This code works fine:

```
Dim tBoxes = From t In MainForm.Frame2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).ToList
tBoxes.ToList().ForEach(Sub(c) c.DataBindings.Clear())
```

Why can't I combine them into the one line below (I believe it's related to the fact that the first line above does not set tBoxes to a list but remains an `IEnumerable` even though I am calling `ToList`, why is this?)

```
Dim tBoxes = From t In MainForm.Frame2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).ToList.ForEach(Sub(c) c.DataBindings.Clear())
```

This code results in an error

> Expression does not produce a value

This might seem like much ado about nothing but it's not just the reduction to one line, I'd like to understand what's going on here.

VB.NET 2010

Comment: `.ToList` needs the parens `.ToList()`

Comment: `ForEach(Sub(c)...` is a sub and doesnt return a value (and you do not *need* the parens except in C#, they are a good idea though )

Comment: Worth noting that in the first example `tBoxes.ToList()` takes a list and turns it into a list. That can be useful if you need a copy for some reason, but since you then act on every (reference type, so affecting the first list) item in the copy and then throw it away, it's just a waste.

Comment: Lets backup a minute, why does this not return a list, if I hover over tBoxes it says it is still an IEnumberable:
            Dim tBoxes = From t In MainForm.Frame2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).ToList()

Comment: whereas something like this line gives an acutal list of TextBoxes:
            Dim list = (From t In New List(Of TextBox) Select t).ToList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the `ToList` call, but [List.ForEach Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) which is `Sub`, hence does not have a result and cannot be assigned to a variable.

If you want to use a single line, remove `Dim tBoxes =`.

**Update** In fact there is another problem in the above code.

```
Dim tBoxes = From t In MainForm.Frame2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).ToList
```

is equivalent to

```
Dim tBoxList = MainForm.Frame2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).ToList
Dim tBoxes = From t in tBoxList
```

so obviously `tBoxes` is `IEnumerable<TextBox>`.

Since the `from t In ..` part is unnecessary in this case, the "oneliner" should be something like this

```
MainForm.Frame2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).ToList.ForEach(Sub(c) c.DataBindings.Clear())
```

If you really need a query part, to avoid such confusions, don't forget to enclose it in `(..)` before calling `ToList` or other methods like `Count`, `Any` etc., like this

```
(from t In MainForm.Frame2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)).ToList.ForEach(Sub(c) c.DataBindings.Clear())
```

Comment: still not quite sure why both of these return an IEnumberable:   `From t In MainForm.Frame2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)` and `From t In MainForm.Frame2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).ToList()`      but yes removing the query part works: `MainForm.Frame2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).ToList.ForEach(Sub(c) c.DataBindings.Clear())`

Comment: @BrusterMulligan the result of `from t in something` is always `IEnumerable`. `ToList` (method call) has higher priority, so in the second case the result of `OfType` method is converted to List, and then `from t In list` converts it back to `IEnumerable`. As I mentioned at the end, parenthesis are needed to change that priority, to make `ToList` be called after the query.

Comment: ahh ok, got it now, interesting. thanks for providing the details.

Answer (score 1):

Small description but enough to understand

```
From t In MainForm.Frame2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox) 'Filter all object of type text box  
.ToList  'Convert IEnemerable(Of TextBox) to a IList type. 
.ForEach(Sub(c) c.DataBindings.Clear())' Iterate through list and remove bindg of each text box
```

Issue is that .ForEach does not return any value so that there is nothing to assign the tBoxes object that you have created. It is just like a void method or Sub in VB.net.